# Symfony2 - Doctrine2 QueryBuilder WHERE IN ManyToMany field

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

:)

Thank you in advance for helping me with this issue:

I've an entity Hotel which has a ManyToMany relation with an entity HotelService

how can i build (with QueryBuilder if possible) one query to select all hotels having a subset of services given as array parameter?

Example: H1(S1, S2, S3, S4), H2(S2, S3, S4), H3(S1, S2, S3)

Querying with subset (S1, S2) has to return H1 and H3.

I have tried many things, this is some code extract:

```
public function findByServices($services) {
 
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('hotel')
 
            ->addSelect('location')
 
            ->addSelect('country')
 
            ->addSelect('billing')
 
            ->addSelect('services')
 
            ->innerJoin('hotel.billing', 'billing')
 
            ->innerJoin('hotel.location', 'location')
 
            ->innerJoin('location.city', 'city')
 
            ->innerJoin('location.country', 'country');
 
            ->innerJoin('hotel.services', 'services');
 
    $i = 0;
    $arrayIds = array();
    foreach ($services as $service) {
        $arrayIds[$i++] = $service->getId();
    }
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('services', $arrayIds))->getQuery();
}
```

This code return all hotels for which there is ONE service id in $arrayIds.

I want the opposite (hotels for which services contain ALL ids in $arrayIds).

Of course, inversing parameters in expr()->in doesn't solve the problem, and create bad parameters errors.

Can somebody help me please? (sorry for my bad english) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your solution you can make use of `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with `HAVING` and `GROUP BY` clauses

```
public function findByServices($services)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('hotel')
        ->addSelect('location')
        ->addSelect('country')
        ->addSelect('billing')
        ->addSelect('services')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  services.id) AS total_services')
        ->innerJoin('hotel.billing', 'billing')
        ->innerJoin('hotel.location', 'location')
        ->innerJoin('location.city', 'city')
        ->innerJoin('location.country', 'country')
        ->innerJoin('hotel.services', 'services');
    $i = 0;
    $arrayIds = array();
    foreach ($services as $service) {
        $arrayIds[$i++] = $service->getId();
    }
    $qb->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('services', $arrayIds))
        ->addGroupBy('hotel.id')
        ->having('total_services = '.count($arrayIds))
        ->getQuery();
}
```

---

In above query i have added one more select as counting distinct service ids for each hotel i.e

> ->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  services.id) AS HIDDEN total_services')

Then i also need a group by for that count  so i added

> ->addGroupBy('hotel.id')

---

Now here comes the tricky part as you mentioned that you need hotel that have all the service ids like ids (1,2,3) so hotels that contains these 3 service should be returned when we use in its performs or operation like `where servid_id = 1 or servid_id = 2 servid_id = 3` which is exactly you don't want the `AND` operation that hotel must have these 3 so i converted this logic by having part

> ->having('total_services = '.count($arrayIds))

Now `total_services` is a virtual alias for the query and holds the distinct count for each hotel so i have compared this count to the count of provided ids in `IN()` part this will return the hotels which must contains these services

---

### [`GROUP BY and HAVING Clause`](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#group-by-and-having-clause)