# Doctrine ORM: filter articles by 2 categories

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, orm

In our online shop we are selling spare parts for industrial computer systems. Therefore we have 2 main categories: spare parts and computer systems. Users can either search their needed spare parts via the spare parts category or via the computer system. If a user selected his computer system on the homepage, he should get a list of spare parts categories matching with his computer system.

Therefore i need to query all spare parts categories and filter them by all articles, that are also in the category of the preselected computer system. Otherwise the user could see an empty category.

I have 2 doctrine entites: article and category - each of them related many to many to the other:

Category Entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="categories")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository")
 */
class Category extends ModelEntity
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Models\Article\Article")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_categories",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryID", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleID", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      }
     * )
     */
    private $articles;
```

Article Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles")
 */
class Article extends ModelEntity
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Models\Category\Category")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="articles_categories",
     *      joinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="articleID", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      },
     *      inverseJoinColumns={
     *          @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categoryID", referencedColumnName="id")
     *      }
     * )
     */
    protected $categories;
```

I'm trying to query all categories with articles in 2 categories. For example: get all categories, that has articles in "this" category, but only where same articles are also in "that" category.

Unfortunately i have no idea, how to do this. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: So in any 2 categories, or 2 of your selected categories?

Comment: In 2 selected categories - for example: get only categories, which have articles in themself *AND* category 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to M Khalid Junaid i finally figured it out.
This is my final query:

```
// select all active root categories from the online shop
$builder = Shopware()->Models()->createQueryBuilder();
$builder->from('Models\Category\Category', 'c')
        ->select('c as category')
        ->andWhere('c.active = 1')
        ->andWhere('c.parentId = 0');

// if the user already selected his computer system,
// only get articles, that are in both categories: the
// category of this particular computer system and the
// category of spare parts
if ($this->computerSystemCategoryId) {

    $builder->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT a2.id) AS total_system_articles')
            ->leftJoin('c.articles', 'a2')
            ->leftJoin('a2.categories', 'c2')
            ->groupBy('c.id')
            ->having('total_system_articles > 0')
            ->andWhere($builder->expr()->in('c2', [$this->computerSystemCategoryId]));

}

$query = $builder->getQuery();
$categories = $query->getResult();
```

With this query i can get only the spare parts, that are associated with the particular spare parts category, but also with the particular computer system category id.

Comment: Glad you found it

Answer (score 1):

To find categories who belongs to given list of articles (each category must has an association with each article from given list) then you can make use of some aggregation

```
$articleIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->addSelect('COUNT(DISTINCT  a.id) AS HIDDEN total_articles')
           ->innerJoin('c.articles', 'a')
           ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('a', $articleIds))
           ->groupBy('c.id')
           ->having('total_articles = '.count($articleIds))
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult();
```

- [**Symfony2 - Doctrine2 QueryBuilder WHERE IN ManyToMany field**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25576818/symfony2-doctrine2-querybuilder-where-in-manytomany-field/25577184#25577184)
- [**Doctrine QueryBuilder: ManyToOne Relationship where more than one subEntity must match**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46930493/doctrine-querybuilder-manytoone-relationship-where-more-than-one-subentity-must?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [**Sql/Doctrine query to find data with multiple condition with Many to Many associations**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239178/sql-doctrine-query-to-find-data-with-multiple-condition-with-many-to-many-associ?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [**Convert SQL with subquery to Doctrine Query Builder**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50682967/convert-sql-with-subquery-to-doctrine-query-builder?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks for your help - it really opened my eyes a bit. Although, your query gets all categories, that have specific articles in it. I need a query, that gets all categories, whose articles are also assigned to another specific category. Something like:

`$qb->select('c, COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) AS total_articles')
    ->from('Models\Category\Category', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c.articles', 'a')
    ->innerJoin('a.categories', 'c2')
    ->add('where', $qb->expr()->in('c2', 42636))
    ->groupBy('c.id')
    ->having('total_articles = 2');`

Comment: @chris.ribal Can you add sample data for category and articles and on basis of this include your expected output in your question, that would be very helpful to understand you problem

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid i updated the question and included a basic description of what i'm trying to achieve. Also i found the solution in my case and posted it as a separate answer. Thank you for putting me on the right track!